# How to store username and password in a secure way

Tags: java, passwords, password-encryption

I am building an java web application that has to communicate with the active directory (AD) server and another web service (WS) server. Both AD & WS requires authentication using a same set of username and password. How should I store the username and password in a secure way?

I am currently thinking of storing the encrypted password in database, while the key stores in the web application which bundles in the .war file. Application server and database server are in different machines. Is it an appropriate way to accomplish this task? Please suggest if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Any chance of injecting it using a property or environment variable?

Comment: I thought of storing username and password in properties file before. In my case, using properties file requires deployment of the web application which is done by another team and a series of procedures is needed. This may take a day to update it if the password is changed, which is not preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try centralized user authentication as a service and use cookie to store user info.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the pass words and username and store it in the place you want. And decode it after reading it.
Fortunately for this work in my app I have created a library package having classes to encode and decode strings. You should provide me your email so that I can send the jar file to you.

To encode you can use similar codes to this one

```
 String encode(String s){
char[] ret=new char[s.length];
for(int i=0;i&amp;lt;s.length();i++)
{
 ret[i]=(char)((s.charAt(i)+23)*i+12);
 }
String encoded=new String(ret);
return encoded;
 }
```

You can write opposite to decode the encoded string.
Don't copy it use your own algorithms

Comment: **This is extremely dangerous! Do not use this!** If an attacker gains access to the server, encoding does *absolutely nothing*. Encoding is not encrypting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `MessageDigest` class that supports cryptographic functions (MD5, for example) and use it to transfrom string password on the client to the byte array, and transfer it to the server. You don not need to hold the string on the server, and there will be only comparing of encoded byte arrays.
Example:

```
String password = null;
byte[] encoded = null;
try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    encoded = md.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
} 
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The requested web service is not developed by us. The request has to be sent in the following form: http://server.com/service1.ws?username=xxx&password=yyy. I cannot send the password in digested form which is not allowed by the web service.